# Calculation with same group city in SQL

Tags: sqlite

I have the following SQLite table:

```
ID  City Product    Value
1   A   Lubs        22
2   A   Ethanol     14
3   A   S500        10
4   A   S10         13
5   A   Biodiesel   40
6   A   Gasoline    15
7   B   Lubs        8
8   B   Ethanol     20
9   B   S500        12
10  B   S10         15
11  B   Biodiesel   50
12  B   Gasoline    8
```

What I need (final result):

```
City    Product    Value_Pond
A       Lubs       22
A       S500       =10*88% + 40*12%
A       S10        =13*88% + 40*12%
A       Gasoline   =14*27% + 15*73%
B       Lubs       8
B       S500       =12*88% + 50*12%
B       S10        =15*88% + 50*12%
B       Gasoline   =20*27% + 8*73%
```

For each city, I need to make some maths for S500, S10 and Gasoline. Explaining for city A:

1. S500: S500 Value * 88% + Biodiesel Value * 12% = 13,6
2. S10: S10 Value * 88% + Biodiesel Value * 12% = 16,24
3. Gasoline: Ethanol Value * 27% + Gasoline Value * 73% = 14,73
4. Lubs has the same value - no math needed.

The same will hapen for city B and so on and so forth...

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression and `MAX()` window function to get each result:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT City, Product,
         ROUND(
           CASE Product
             WHEN 'Lubs' THEN Value 
             WHEN 'S500' THEN Value * 0.88 + MAX(CASE WHEN Product = 'Biodiesel' THEN Value END) OVER (PARTITION BY City) * 0.12
             WHEN 'S10' THEN Value * 0.88 + MAX(CASE WHEN Product = 'Biodiesel' THEN Value END) OVER (PARTITION BY City) * 0.12
             WHEN 'Gasoline' THEN Value * 0.73 + MAX(CASE WHEN Product = 'Ethanol' THEN Value END) OVER (PARTITION BY City) * 0.27  
           END,
           2
        ) Value_Pond  
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE Value_Pond IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY City, 
         CASE Product
           WHEN 'Lubs' THEN 1
           WHEN 'S500' THEN 2
           WHEN 'S10' THEN 3
           WHEN 'Gasoline' THEN 4
         END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/tXTs-3gj).